# How to disable a doctrine filter in a param converter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I'm using the doctrine softdeleteable extension on a project and have my controller action set up as such.

```
/**
 * @Route("address/{id}/")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @ParamConverter("address", class="MyBundle:Address")
 * @Security("is_granted('view', address)")
 */
public function getAddressAction(Address $address)
{
```

This works great as it returns NotFound if the object is deleted, however I want to grant access to users with ROLE_ADMIN to be able to see soft deleted content.

Does there already exist a way to get the param converter to disable the filter or am I going to have to create my own custom param converter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no existing ways to do it, but I've solved this problem by creating my own annotation, that disables `softdeleteable` filter before `ParamConverter` does its job.

*AcmeBundle/Annotation/IgnoreSoftDelete.php:*

```
namespace AcmeBundle\Annotation;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target({"CLASS", "METHOD"})
 */
class IgnoreSoftDelete extends Annotation { }
```

*AcmeBundle/EventListener/AnnotationListener.php:*

```
namespace AcmeBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Reader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class AnnotationListener {

    protected $reader;

    public function __construct(Reader $reader) {
        $this->reader = $reader;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {
        if (!is_array($controller = $event->getController())) {
            return;
        }

        list($controller, $method, ) = $controller;

        $this->ignoreSoftDeleteAnnotation($controller, $method);
    }

    private function readAnnotation($controller, $method, $annotation) {
        $classReflection = new \ReflectionClass(ClassUtils::getClass($controller));
        $classAnnotation = $this->reader->getClassAnnotation($classReflection, $annotation);

        $objectReflection = new \ReflectionObject($controller);
        $methodReflection = $objectReflection->getMethod($method);
        $methodAnnotation = $this->reader->getMethodAnnotation($methodReflection, $annotation);

        if (!$classAnnotation && !$methodAnnotation) {
            return false;
        }

        return [$classAnnotation, $classReflection, $methodAnnotation, $methodReflection];
    }

    private function ignoreSoftDeleteAnnotation($controller, $method) {
        static $class = 'AcmeBundle\Annotation\IgnoreSoftDelete';

        if ($this->readAnnotation($controller, $method, $class)) {
            $em = $controller->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
            $em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
        }
    }

}
```

*AcmeBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:*

```
services:
    acme.annotation_listener:
        class: AcmeBundle\EventListener\AnnotationListener
        arguments: [@annotation_reader]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller }
```

*AcmeBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php:*

```
namespace AcmeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use AcmeBundle\Annotation\IgnoreSoftDelete;
use AcmeBundle\Entity\User;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}")
     * @IgnoreSoftDelete
     * @Template
     */
    public function indexAction(User $user) {
        return ['user' => $user];
    }

}
```

Annotation can be applied to individual action methods and to entire controller classes.

Comment: FYI: in more recent symfony versions the controller's `get` method is protected and can't be called in the listener's `ignoreSoftDeleteAnnotation` method. You can pass the EntityManager in the constructor, just like the Reader and rely on dependency injection. Also FilterControllerEvent is deprecated since symfony 4.3 and one should use ControllerEvent instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Entity for this, customizing a repository method like this:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity;

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}")
     * @Entity("post", expr="repository.findDisableFilter(id)")
     */
     public function disable(Post $post): JsonResponse
    {
        ...
    }
```

and then in your repository class:

```
    public function findDisableFilter(mixed $id): mixed
    {
        $filterName = 'your-filter-name';
        $filters = $this->getEntityManager()->getFilters();
        if ($filters->has($filterName) && $filters->isEnabled($filterName)) {
            $filters->disable($filterName);
        }

        return $this->find($id);
    }
```